# Problem with simple SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This relates to a webpage that should show all upcoming events, and mark any that are in the current user's diary.

**diary table**
diary_id
member_id
event_id

**event table**
event_id
region_id
...

**region table**
region_id
...

**member table**
member_id
...

QUERY:

```
SELECT event.*, region.name, diary.diary_id 
FROM event, region 
LEFT JOIN diary on diary.member_id = 10 AND diary.event_id = event.event_id
WHERE region.region_id = event.region_id AND `date` >= NOW()
```

This is returning unknown column event.event_id and I can't figure out why. I'm no SQL whiz but expected this would just work and give me a NULL in the diary_id column for all events that are not in the user's diary

Comment: Can you edit the post to include the actual complete error message, formatted as code?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the event ID column is named `event_id`?  What do you see if you start up the MySQL client and type `describe event;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing `join` syntax. Try this instead.

```
SELECT event.*,
       region.name,
       diary.diary_id
FROM   event
       INNER JOIN region
         ON region.region_id = event.region_id
       LEFT JOIN diary
         ON diary.member_id = 10
            AND diary.event_id = event.event_id
WHERE  `date` >= NOW()
```

**Update**

Your problem with not finding `event_id` is because of this `FROM event, region`. It can't find `event_id` in the `on` clause. Change your query as suggested above but it would also be possible to fix it by switching places of the tables to `FROM region, event`. Don't do that. Use the new join syntax introduced to the SQL language some 20 years ago.

Comment: +1. Basically, when a comma-separated list of tables is followed by a JOIN clause, only the table that immediately precedes the clause takes part in the join, not all of the list. Or, in other words, between these two kinds of operators, the comma join and the JOIN clause, the latter takes precedence over the former.

Comment: Thanks. Worked. I probably need to learn a bit more about Joins ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wouldn't put `diary.member_id = 10`  in the Join:

```
SELECT event.*, region.name, diary.diary_id 
FROM `event`, region 
LEFT JOIN diary ON diary.event_id = event.event_id
WHERE region.region_id = event.region_id AND `date` >= NOW() AND diary.member_id = 10
```

Are you sure that `event.event_id` is not `event.id`?

Comment: If you move `diary.member_id = 10` to the where clause you are no longer doing a `left outer join` against `diary`. The result will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put diary.member_id = 10 in the where clause if you want to do the left join. In PL/SQL this will turn your left join into a join without asking you

The below should do better:

```
SELECT event.*, region.name, diary.diary_id 
FROM event
JOIN region on region.region_id = event.region_id  
LEFT JOIN ( select diary_id, event_id
              from diary 
             where diary.member_id = 10 ) diary
       ON diary.event_id = event.event_id
WHERE `date` >= NOW()
```